# How to change in Django Admin the default form (dropdown list) for a foreignKey model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to change in my django administration page the form of a field. In my model I have the 'user' as foreign key to another model. When I create a new '**programare**' in the administration page the default form-field for user it's a dropdown with all entries of '**Cont**' model. It's dizzy to search the right one, so I want to change that **dropdown** with a **plain-text input** or an **autocomplete form**.

```
class Programare(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(to=Cont, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='programari')
   ...
```

[image: That form I want to be an autocomplete or at least an plain-text like the one above it.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer for my question. For django ^2.0 admin

```
class ProgramareAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Programare
    autocomplete_fields = ['user']

admin.site.register(Programare, ProgramareAdmin)
```

[image]